# WPF База данных. Не получается добавить данные в таблицу БД

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть класс Presenter:

```
    class Presenter
{
    ContextDB context = new ContextDB();

    public DateTime _Date { get; set; }
    public string _Event { get; set; }

    public Presenter(DateTime DateFromForm, string EventFormForm)
    {
        _Date = DateFromForm;
        _Event = EventFormForm;
    }        

    public void NewEvent()
    {
        try
        {
            Table NewEvent = new Table
            {
                Date = _Date,
                Event = _Event
            };

            context.Table.Add(NewEvent);

            context.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Запись добавлена!");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ddd");
        }                 
    }              
}
```

Так пытаюсь добавить данные в таблицу с помощью кнопки:

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter add = new Presenter(datePicker.DisplayDate, textBox.Text);
        add.NewEvent();
    }
```

Форма, где вводятся данные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема и почему данные не добавляются?

Comment: дайте угадаю, у вас БД - это файлик в проекте и в него не добавляются данные, когда в добавляете данные в дебаге, и при этом ошибок нет, да?

Comment: @tym32167 ахахахаха, да. Бд - .mdf. Т.е. не получится добавлять данные?

Comment: все получится. Вы когда компилируете программу и запускаете, она запускается из папки `ваш проект\bin\debug` - там она и создает копию БД, с которой работает. А вы проверяете данные (точнее, что их нет) в файле, который лежит где то рядом с исходниками (наверное прямо в папке проекта). Зайдите в ваш `bin\debug` каталог и ищите БД там